# Rotating a bitmap using GDI+ then converting to HDC

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, drawing, gdi+

I am trying to do what the title says.

Below is the code which is supposed to return an HDC with the rotated icon.
I am not sure why it isn't returning anything. When I try to draw the returned HDC nothing appears and it isn't an error in my drawing I tested it.

```
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;

GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

Gdiplus::Bitmap SrcBitmap(L"H:\\Company\\iOG\\blue_arrow.tif", FALSE);

Gdiplus::Graphics DstGraphics(&SrcBitmap);

Gdiplus::REAL angle = lAngle;
DstGraphics.ResetTransform();
DstGraphics.RotateTransform(angle);
DstGraphics.TranslateTransform(SrcBitmap.GetWidth() / 2.0f, SrcBitmap.GetHeight() / 2.0f, Gdiplus::MatrixOrderAppend);
DstGraphics.DrawImage(&SrcBitmap, -((INT)SrcBitmap.GetWidth() / 2), -((INT)SrcBitmap.GetHeight() / 2), SrcBitmap.GetWidth(), SrcBitmap.GetHeight());

HBITMAP hBmp;
SrcBitmap.GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color::Transparent, &hBmp);
HDC dcIcon = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
SelectObject(dcIcon, hBmp);

return dcIcon;
```

Comment: You seem have forgotten to check for errors.

Comment: You can't convert a bitmap to `HDC`. Please explain in simple terms what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - where you view conversion bitmap ( `HBITMAP` you mean ?) to `HDC` ? exist selection bitmap to dc which is correct `SelectObject(hIcon, hBmp);` (strange that dc named `hIcon`)

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. I have an icon (blue arrow) I need to rotate the icon and display it on the game's map. I have the icon in .gif, .tif, .bmp, .jpg

Comment: I also changed the name of hIcon to dcIcon

Comment: You propably need to use different source and destination bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

`Gdiplus::Bitmap::GetHBITMAP` creates a new bitmap handle. This handle should be deleted when it is no longer needed. The way above code is setup, the bitmap handle is lost and it is impossible to cleanup. This will lead to resource leak and the program will eventually stop working.

You should be after the bitmap handle for the modified image, not the device context where that bitmap is drawn. You can modify the code as follows:

```
HBITMAP convert(const wchar_t* filename, UINT& w, UINT& h)
{
    Gdiplus::Bitmap src(filename, FALSE);
    if(0 != src.GetLastStatus())
        return NULL;

    w = src.GetWidth();
    h = src.GetHeight();
    Gdiplus::Graphics gr(&src);
    gr.ResetTransform();
    gr.RotateTransform(45);
    gr.TranslateTransform(w / 2.0f, h / 2.0f, Gdiplus::MatrixOrderAppend);
    gr.DrawImage(&src, -(INT)w / 2, -(INT)h / 2);// , w, h);
    HBITMAP hbitmap = NULL;
    src.GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color::Transparent, &hbitmap);
    return hbitmap;
}

void draw(HDC hdc)
{
    UINT w, h;
    HBITMAP hbitmap = convert(L"filename.bmp", w, h);
    if(hbitmap)
    {
        HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
        DeleteDC(memdc);
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);
    }
}
```

In addition, a call to `GdiplusStartup` should end with `GdiplusShutdown`

`SelectObject(dcIcon, hBmp);` should be modified to return the old bitmap handle. Old handle should be restored at the end.